# Post page to Pocket (Read it Later) programmatically

Tags: ruby

I need to add pages to [Pocket](http://getpocket.com) from my programm. I have found the page http://getpocket.com/edit which [allow to post pages](http://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/articles/661928-how-to-manually-save-to-pocket).

Here is my code:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://getpocket.com/edit')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'url' => 'http://www.google.com')
puts res.body
```

I have run it but the new page didn't appear in Pocket Queue.  Why and how can I fix it ?

Is there any other way to post the page to Pocket programmatically ?

Comment: Why the backslashes in the url?

Comment: Also, the title of the page is "How to Manually Save to Pocket". It doesn't say it will work for programmatic access. I think you have to also provide auth data (cookie or whatever it is they use).

Comment: I have fixed it doesn't help.

Comment: "when I run it nothing happens" - what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Find the saved page in my Pocket Queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For programmatic access you should use their API. Here's the documentation: http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/overview

And here's how you [add an item](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/add):

> Adding a Single Item
>
> To save an item to a user’s Pocket list, you’ll make a single request to the /v3/add endpoint.
>
> Method URL
>   https://getpocket.com/v3/add